# I would like to check the status of a list of twitter user ids

Tags: python, twitter, twitter-oauth

As stated in the question, I would like to check the status of a list of twitter user ids. I had about 20k twitter users. I was able to get the timelines of about half of them. The other have are probably either suspended, deactivated, or have 0 tweets. I found this script online that supposedly allow for checking the status of a twitter user. Here is the script (https://github.com/dbrgn/Twitter-User-Checker/blob/master/checkuser.py):
`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2

# Twitter User Checker
# Author: Danilo Bargen
# License: GPLv3

import sys
import tweepy
import urllib2
try:
    import json
except ImportError:
    import simplejson as json
from datetime import datetime

auth = tweepy.AppAuthHandler("xxx", "xxxx")

api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)

if (not api):
    print ("Can't Authenticate")
    sys.exit(-1)

# Continue with rest of code


try:
    user = sys.argv[1]
except IndexError:
    print 'Usage: checkuser.py [username]'
    sys.exit(-1)

url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?id=%s' % user

try:
    request = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    status = request.code
    data = request.read()
except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
    status = e.code
    data = e.read()

data = json.loads(data)

print data

if status == 403:
     print "helloooooooo"
#    if 'suspended' in data['error']:
#        print 'User %s has been suspended' % user
#    else:
#        print 'Unknown response'
elif status == 404:
    print 'User %s not found' % user
elif status == 200:
    days_active = (datetime.now() - datetime.strptime(data['created_at'],
                   '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y')).days
    print 'User %s is active and has posted %s tweets in %s days' % \
             (user, data['statuses_count'], days_active)
else:
    print 'Unknown response'
```

`

I get the following error: 
`File "twitter_status_checker.py", line 16, in <module>
    auth = tweepy.AppAuthHandler("xxx", "xxxx")
  File "/Users/aloush/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tweepy/auth.py", line 170, in __init__
    'but got %s instead' % data.get('token_type'))
tweepy.error.TweepError: Expected token_type to equal "bearer", but got None instead`

Could anyone help me fix the error as well as allow the script to check for a list of users rather than one user for each run.

Here is a list of the HTTP Status Codes I would like to check for: https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/response-codes

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you failed to authenticate twitter. For the latest version (3.5), tweepy uses [OAuthHander](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.5.0/auth_tutorial.html) to authenticate. Please check how to use Tweepy. And also the linked script you used is to check the account one by one, which could be very slow.

To check the status of a large set of Twitter accounts by Tweepy, particularly if you want to know the reason why it is inactive (e.g., not found, suspended), you need to be aware of the followings:

1. Which API should be used?

Twitter provides two related APIs, one is [user/show](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/users/show) and the other is [user/lookup](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/users/lookup). The former one returns the profile of one specified user, while the later one returns profile of a block of up to 100 users. The corresponding tweepy APIs are [`API.get_user`](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.5.0/api.html#API.get_user) and [`API.lookup_users`](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/v3.5.0/tweepy/api.py) (I cannot find it in the documentation, but it does exist in code). Definitely, you should use the second one. However, when there exist some inactive users, the `lookup_users` API returns only these are active. This means that you have to call `get_user` API to get the very detail reason for inactive accounts.

2. How to determine the status of a user?

Of course, you should pay attention to the [response code](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/response-codes) provided by Twitter. However, when using tweepy, instead of the HTTP ERROR CODES, you should pay more attention on the ERROR MESSAGE. Here are some common cases:

- If the profile is successfully fetched, it is an active user;
- Otherwise, we could check the error code:

  - 50  User not found.
  - 63  User has been suspended.
  - ... maybe more code about the user account

For tweepy, when the profile is failed to fetch, a [TweepyError](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.5.0/api.html#TweepError) is raised. And the TweepyError.message[0] is the error message from twitter API.

Okay, here are the logic to process

(1) Divide the large block of user into pieces of size of 100;

(2) for each of these pieces, do (3) and (4);

(3) call `lookup_users`, the returned users will be treated as the active users and the remaining users will be treated as inactive users;

(4) call `get_user` for each of the inactive users to get the detailed reason.

Here is a sample code for you:

```
import logging

import tweepy

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def to_bulk(a, size=100):
    """Transform a list into list of list. Each element of the new list is a
    list with size=100 (except the last one).
    """
    r = []
    qt, rm = divmod(len(a), size)
    i = -1
    for i in range(qt):
        r.append(a[i * size:(i + 1) * size])
    if rm != 0:
        r.append(a[(i + 1) * size:])
    return r


def fast_check(api, uids):
    """ Fast check the status of specified accounts.
    Parameters
    ---------------
        api: tweepy API instance
        uids: account ids

    Returns
    ----------
    Tuple (active_uids, inactive_uids).
        `active_uids` is a list of active users and
        `inactive_uids` is a list of inactive uids,
            either supended or deactivated.
    """
    try:
        users = api.lookup_users(user_ids=uids,
                                 include_entities=False)
        active_uids = [u.id for u in users]
        inactive_uids = list(set(uids) - set(active_uids))
        return active_uids, inactive_uids
    except tweepy.TweepError as e:
        if e[0]['code'] == 50 or e[0]['code'] == 63:
            logger.error('None of the users is valid: %s', e)
            return [], inactive_uids
        else:
            # Unexpected error
            raise


def check_inactive(api, uids):
    """ Check inactive account, one by one.
    Parameters
    ---------------
    uids : list
        A list of inactive account

    Returns
    ----------
        Yield tuple (uid, reason). Where `uid` is the account id,
        and `reason` is a string.
    """
    for uid in uids:
        try:
            u = api.get_user(user_id=uid)
            logger.warning('This user %r should be inactive', uid)
            yield (u, dict(code=-1, message='OK'))
        except tweepy.TweepyError as e:
            yield (uid, e[0][0])


def check_one_block(api, uids):
    """Check the status of user for one block (<100). """
    active_uids, inactive_uids = fast_check(api, uids)
    inactive_users_status = list(check_inactive(api, inactive_uids))
    return active_uids, inactive_users_status


def check_status(api, large_uids):
    """Check the status of users for any size of users. """
    active_uids = []
    inactive_users_status = []
    for uids in to_bulk(large_uids, size=100):
        au, iu = check_one_block(api, uids)
        active_uids += au
        inactive_users_status += iu
    return active_uids, inactive_users_status


def main(twitter_crendient, large_uids):
    """ The main function to call check_status. """
    # First prepare tweepy API
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(twitter_crendient['consumer_key'],
                               twitter_crendient['consumer_secret'])
    auth.set_access_token(twitter_crendient['access_token'],
                          twitter_crendient['access_token_secret'])
    api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)
    # Then, call check_status
    active_uids, inactive_user_status = check_status(api, large_uids)
```

Because of the lack of data, I never test the code. There may be bugs, you should take care of them.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thank you @rojeeer. I am only interested in knowing whether user x in X is active or not, if not why?, was it suspended, deactivated, etc.?

The code you wrote above doesn't give back the type of error. For example, I pass this list of users: `
uids = ['858379747549749249','862798674891608064','869677035291127808','823878900413583363','863111039986135040','851767792521146368','849779141734002688','753953185857933312','863051428805398529','847459130017067008', '1694924514'] `and only two of them returned because they are active.